# Suggested edit title is truncated in inline review

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, user-interface, title

I happened to browse a question with a pending suggested edit, which I have the privilege to review. Ok, click on `edit(1)`.

[image: screenshot]

That title looks incomplete. But in the [actual suggestion](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8938), there are more words at the end; they're visible when browsing the suggestion's page but not when reviewing the edit inline. This is especially annoying as there's no link from the inline suggestion to the standalone page.