# Suggested edit still not in the queue after 1 hour

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, suggested-edits

I happened to notice [this suggested edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8938) while browsing [the question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18927/quick-and-simple-question-regarding-pgp). But the [review list page](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/review) says there are 0 pending suggested edit reviews on the site. If I click on “Suggested Edits” anyway, I'm told that [There are no items for you to review.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits)

Could it be caching? This suggestion is over 1 hour old, delaying suggested edit reviews for 1 hour isn't reasonable.

Or maybe the explanation is that I'd first clicked on the `edit(1)` button to review the suggestion online? But since I had not taken any action, this should not have affected my personal view of the suggested edit review queue.

<sub>(I reviewed the edit before posting this bug report.)</sub>

Comment: Did you skip it instead of doing nothing?

Comment: @Servy No, all I did is to click on `edit(1)`. I *might* have clicked outside and caused the suggested edit pop-up to disappear before I went to look for it in the review queue ([for reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238896/suggested-edit-title-is-truncated-in-inline-review)), I don't remember. I definitely did not click on any button.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of [late last week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039), we're now giving suggested-edit reviewers a limited period of exclusivity. What this means:

- When you view a pending suggested edit, the system will avoid assigning that edit to any other reviewers until you've submitted your review or a reasonable period of time (currently 3 minutes) has passed. The number of "in review" tasks is tracked, and the main /review page updates the counts accordingly.
- We don't actually *block* multiple reviewers, so if you open the suggested edit from the question page (rather than being assigned it by the system via /review) you'll be given the opportunity to review it regardless of who else currently has it open.
- If you don't explicitly take action on a review (approve / reject / improve / skip), it won't be assigned to anyone else (or appear in the counts shown under /review) until your period of exclusivity expires.

Note that while this behavior is new to suggested edits, it isn't new to review - single-review tasks (first posts / late answers) have had this behavior for a while.

Comment: So by viewing the suggested edit inline, I locked everyone out, even myself? That last bit doesn't sound right, but I guess it's an unusual edge case.

Comment: Well, you didn't lock yourself out in that you were already viewing it (and could go back to viewing it via the route you originally arrived at it - which you did) - but yes, you locked it from being *automatically* assigned to anyone, including yourself.